# showing different output for same input(nearly)

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

Guys I am new to competitive programming ,I am facing a small problem
while giving input
In the question number of vertices are starting from 1 to n
But i write the program considering that nodes are starting from 0

But when i am giving input the test cases by reducing 1 from each vertices for each edge my program is running fine out of the given test cases;

```
given test case;
1(checking for first one only otherwise 2 was given)
4
1 2
1 3
3 4
2 2
1 2
3 4

my test case(after reducing 1 from edges):
1
4
0 1
0 2
2 3
2 2
0 1
2 3
```

Link for the question:

https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/29036-the-story-of-a-tree-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1542565481&Signature=WoegY4gKUz0OUDEQ3n2UT80FUc0%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dthe-story-of-a-tree-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf

But when i am changing what i am changing
            `graph[(u-1)][(v-1)] = 1;`
             `graph[(v-1)][(u-1)] = 1;` while taking input edges
also here `alice[(vchild-1)] = (upar-1);`
to take the given test case as it is in my program but my answer coming wrong this time I am also reducing 1 from each vertices while taking input edges Why this is happening?

```
    #pragma warning(disable:4996)
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int visited[1000],parent[100],alice[100];
    struct queue {
        int rear;
        int front;
        int capacity;
        int* array;
    };

    struct queue* createqueue(int capacity) {
        struct queue* Q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
        Q->capacity = capacity;
        Q->front = -1;
        Q->rear = -1;
        Q->array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*capacity);
        return Q;
    }
    int isempty(struct queue* Q) {
        return(Q->front == -1 && Q->rear == -1);

    }
    int isfull(struct queue* Q) {
        return((Q->rear + 1) % Q->capacity == Q->front);

    }
    void push(struct queue* Q, int data) {
        if (isfull(Q))
            return;
        else if (isempty(Q))
        {
            Q->rear = 0;
            Q->front = 0;
            Q->array[Q->rear] = data;
        }
        else {
            Q->rear = ((Q->rear + 1) % Q->capacity);
            Q->array[Q->rear] = data;
        }
    }
    int pop(struct queue* Q) {
        if (isempty(Q))
            return -1;
        else if (Q->rear == Q->front) {
            int temp = Q->rear;
            Q->rear = -1;
            Q->front = -1;
            return(Q->array[temp]);
        }
        else {
            int temp = Q->front;
            Q->front = ((Q->front + 1) % Q->capacity);
            return Q->array[temp];

        }
    }
    void bfs(int** graph ,int ver,int s) {
        struct queue* Q=createqueue(100);
        push(Q, s);
        visited[s] = 1;
        int v, w;
        while (!isempty(Q)) {
            v = pop(Q);
            for (int j = 0; j < ver; j++) {
                if (visited[j] == 0 && graph[v][j] == 1)
                {
                    parent[j] = v;
                    push(Q, j);
                    visited[j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int main() {
        int t;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        while (t) {
            int** graph;
            int i, ver, u, v;
            scanf("%d", &ver);
            graph = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*ver);
            for (i = 0; i < ver; i++)
                graph[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*ver);
            for (int i = 0; i < ver; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ver; j++) {
                    graph[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            //  printf("%d", graph[1][1]);
            for (int j = 0; j < ver - 1; j++) {
                scanf("%d %d", &u, &v);
                graph[u-1][v-1] = 1;
                graph[v-1][u-1] = 1;
            }
            int g, k;
            scanf("%d %d", &g, &k);
            int count = 0, win = 0;
            int vchild, upar;
            for (int i = 0; i < ver; i++)
                alice[i] = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < g; i++) {
                scanf("%d %d", &upar, &vchild);
                alice[vchild-1] = upar-1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                bfs(graph, v, i);
                for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
                    if (alice[i] != -1 && alice[i] == parent[i])
                        count++;
                }
                if (count >= k)
                    win++;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= win && i <= ver; i++) {
                if (win%i == 0 && ver%i == 0) {
                    win = win / i;
                    ver = ver / i;
                }
            }
            printf("%d/%d\n", win, ver);
            t--;
        }




    }
```

Comment: Seems like an excellent case to step through in a debugger so you can see what the difference is. You also missed changing a line in your modified test case.

Comment: sir please help

Comment: Add some error checking on your scanf lines, it returns a value for a reason. Add some printfs at each stage of your program so you can see what's happening as it runs. Change your -1 to -X so you can easily change your program to accept the 1-based and 0-based data so you can compare the output of the print statements you added and see where the difference is. Read through this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Debugging is the most important skill a programmer can have. Learn now while your programs are small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- The scope of your variables is too wide. You reuse variables without resetting them. You can avoid that by using the closest possible scope when defining variables and by initialising them when you define them. (Reusing old values applies to your `parent` and `visited` arrays and to the `count`.
- When you count Alice's correct guesses, the iterating variable of the inner loop is `j`, but yu test `alice[i]` and `parent[i]`.
- When you simplify the fraction, the `if` should be a `while`, otherwise you will miss out on squares and cubes.
- In `main`, you mix up the number of vertices `ver` and the variable `v` a lot.

But why do the outputs differ when you give the zero-indexd variables as input?

As I said above, you use `v` often when you really want `ver`. The variable `v` is used only correctly when you scan the edges and is, of course, different for one-based and zero-based input. Close scpoing is your friend here, too: Make `u` and `v` local to the loop where you scan the edges.

(For what it's worth, I don't think the matrix representation of the graph is useful for larger graphs, because the graph is sparse. You may lose a lot of time when scanning through rows of 100,000 entries repeatedly.)

Comment: Well, revise your code. It has a lot of errors. I've pointed out some. Also heed the advice about debugging given to you in comments. It is you who wants to enter the competition, so it should also be your code. (The idea of such competitions is to learn by programming.)

Comment: I tried my best  whole night sir and i also fix the issues that you told me still i am passing only one test case
I myself tried to make a number of large test and i was passing all of them but still it is not passing system test case and in some one or two test case it is showing segmentaion fault also
please see my code once more [https://ideone.com/5pNxn5 ]

Comment: I will not ask you again only once please

Comment: Looks mich better now `:)`. I don't see any basic faults. But please remove `system("pause")` and make sure that you `free` everything that you allocate. The problem I see with your code is that it is very inefficient. Your adjacency matrix look-up is slow for large, sparse graphs. Your queue, where you allocate or free for each access is slow. You don't need the visited array; you can just check whether the parent has been set already.

Comment: Finally, you don't have to do the full traversal for each node. Here's a question for you which you can solve with pencil and paper: Draw a small tree of, say five nodes. Make a list of all parents, starting from node 1. Then make a list of all parents, starting from a neighbour node of node 1. Where's the difference? Perhaps that can help you to find a more efficient strategy. Good luck!

Comment: thank you sir i pray to god that  he  will always help you well mine also :)

Comment: PLease sir its not passing all the test case ,please see where is the error in logic